# How to present snapshot in a new view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I use this func to take a snapshot,

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view

        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)

        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

then I need to present it, in a new view.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showscreenshot, content: {
    let image = textView.snapshot()
    Image(uiImage: image)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 299, height: 299)
})
```

Why does it not display a photo?

Comment: Can you show code around `image(uiimage:image)`?

Comment: .sheet(isPresented: $showscreenshot, content: {
                    let image = textView.snapshot()
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 299, height: 299)
                    
                })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple problems with your current code. First, you can't do `let image = textView.snapshot()` right in your sheet's `content` parameter. In SwiftUI, all executable code like that should go inside a closure that's *triggered by something*. For example, if you want to take a screenshot when you tap the "Take screenshot" button, it follows that you'd put `let image = textView.snapshot()` inside the button's `action` closure. Then, you'd assign the image to a property `@State var screenshotImage: UIImage?`, which will be passed into the `sheet`.

However, `sheet` behavior has varied between iOS versions. Sometimes it pre-loads its content, sometimes it loads only on presentation. This usually doesn't matter, but it becomes a problem when you're handling optionals like `screenshotImage`. In this case, it's better to use [`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)).

Finally, make sure to add a `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` to your image, otherwise it will be stretched.

```
/// satisfy `sheet(item:)` protocol requirement
extension UIImage: Identifiable {
    public var id: UUID { UUID() }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var screenshotImage: UIImage?
    
    var textView: some View {
        Text("This is a text")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            textView
            
            Button(action: {
                let image = textView.snapshot()
                screenshotImage = image
            }) {
                Text("Take screenshot")
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $screenshotImage) { image in /// use sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) /// prevent image stretching
                .frame(width: 299, height: 299)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Tapping 'Take Screenshot' button presents a modal sheet with screenshot image of 'This is a text' text label]