# How can I get the color of a pixel within a SwiftUI view under iOS?

Tags: swiftui

I have searched quite a bit for this, so let me say that I'm *not* trying to get the color of a pixel *within an image file*. I'm trying to sample the color of a gradient at a particular point on the screen, after the user has scrolled the gradient around.

I found one old example using UIKit to render a view to a UIImage and sample that, but no equivalent for SwiftUI.

I'm targeting iOS 15+, if that makes any difference. What I'm trying to do is use a gradient strip in a scrollview to determine the scrollview's content offset. This is to work around ScrollView's absurd lack of any way to get the scroll offset.

If I put a one-pixel strip below the scrollview's contents that goes from white to black (perhaps masking it with an overlay strip that has a one-pixel hole in it somewhere), I should be able to sample the pixel at a known point in the scrollview pane and use its RGB value to extrapolate where we are in the scrollview's contents.

I'm hoping that this method would be more performant than the existing janky workarounds involving GeometryReader... but admittedly taking screen snapshots sounds like it might not be.

Comment: does this post answer your question, given you take a snapshot of the screen before hand, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78064387/what-is-the-way-to-extract-the-value-of-an-image-pixel-given-that-a-gcpoint-valu/78064713#78064713   For snapshot have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961033/how-to-present-snapshot-in-a-new-view

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Maybe, thanks! Importantly, that seems to operate on a view and not the screen; I need to examine a view that's not visible on screen. I'll add more explanation to my question.